# How to Parallel Process massive JSON to Pandas Dataframe in a Flask RESTful API?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

On a flask server, I am generating a massive `JSON` from a `pandas.DataFrame` and sending it across as `mimetype: application\json`

```
df = df.to_json()
return Response(df, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

Now on the client end, when I am getting this response back,I need to convert it back to a `pandas.dataframe`. This deserialization is very time consuming, but the `REST` service is very time critical.

```
df = response.read_json()
```

OR

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(response)
```

How do I use `Python`'s multiprocessing ability to `spawn multiple parallel processes` to,

- Divide this `JSON` into smaller `JSON Objects`
- Convert those smaller `JSON Objects` to `pandas.DataFrame`
- Append all the `pandas.DataFrame` together

Ideally, making the `JSON` Object into some kind of `dict`ionary would help. But I want speed for the deserialization/conversion.

Shall using `Redis` be a good idea to process this multiple queue structure? In such scenarios, what is the best way to solve the `Large Size vs Time efficiency` problem?

Comment: Without parallel processing, how long does it take?

Comment: ~2.5-3 minutes, I want it to be under 20-30 seconds at max.

Comment: How do you plan on using the dataframe on the client side? Your use case does not make sense. Explain.  Second, pandas IS NOT THREAD SAFE!